# CloudFormation Dynamic Reference To Secret In Different Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I created a secret in `us-east-1` region. I am able to dynamically reference the secret in CloudFormation stack template deployed to region `us-east-1`. The command in template looks something like

```
{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:<accountId>:secret:<secretName>:SecretString:<secretKey>::}}
```

I have another stack template being deployed to region `eu-west-2`. The command to resolve the secret looks exactly the same as described above. However, when deploying, I get CloudFormation error

```
Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: <someId>; Proxy: null)
```

Based on documentation, it should be possible to resolve secrets from different AWS account when full secret ARN is specified as `secret-id`. I was not able to find any cross-region information, hence raising the question here.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-secretsmanager

Am I missing something that I can't import the secret from same account, but different region? Or is this not supported.

Comment: Where exactly in the docs it says you can resolve secrets from a different region?

Comment: @Marcin it is not said, only note about different account is to be found. Hence the question, I don't know if it is possible to fetch from different region, I'll try to rephrase a question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not supported. CloudFormation is a **regional service**, and it can't reference things from other regions. You would have to create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in a form of a lambda function. The function could fetch the secret from other region and return it to your template for further use.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly reference a cross-region secret, but you can [Replicate an AWS Secrets Manager secret to other AWS Regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/create-manage-multi-region-secrets.html) and reference the replica.

1. `us-east-1` template: Replicate the existing `us-east-1` [secret resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html) using `"ReplicaRegions" : [{"Region": "us-west-2"}]`.  This creates a *synched copy* of the secret in the second region.
2. `us-west-2` template: set your dynamic reference to the replicated secret in `us-west-2`.